# Why swagger-codegen-maven-plugin generates method with wrong return type of method and wrong type of arguments?

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger

This is my source method:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"})
@ApiOperation(value = "Приём SMS команды", notes = "Принимает список параметров в формате json, например {\"sender\":\"nip-sos-pusher\",\"version\":\"v0\",\"method\":\"receivedText\",\"rcvtime\":\"2017-11-13T15:07:40.82632+03:00\",\"profile\":\"poisk_ctl\",\"id\":\"b712bc88-2a96-434a-8420-79d35456b8e0\",\"subscriberId\":\"msisdn+79111115782\",\"priority\":0,\"message\":\"OK 79111113849\"}")
@ApiResponses(
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ответ содержит перечень параметров", response = Map.class))
public Map<String, String> onIncomingSm(@ApiParam(value = "Список параметров в формате json", required = true) Map<String, String> params) {
    //some code...
}
```

I generate yaml with swagger-maven-plugin.
this is part of generated yaml with that method:

```
/sms:
post:
  tags:
  - "sms"
  summary: "Приём SMS команды"
  description: "Принимает список параметров в формате json, например {\"sender\"\
    :\"nip-sos-pusher\",\"version\":\"v0\",\"method\":\"receivedText\",\"rcvtime\"\
    :\"2017-11-13T15:07:40.82632+03:00\",\"profile\":\"poisk_ctl\",\"id\":\"b712bc88-2a96-434a-8420-79d35456b8e0\"\
    ,\"subscriberId\":\"msisdn+79111115782\",\"priority\":0,\"message\":\"OK 79111113849\"\
    }"
  operationId: "onIncomingSm"
  consumes:
  - "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  produces:
  - "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  parameters:
  - in: "body"
    name: "body"
    description: "Список параметров в формате json"
    required: true
    schema:
      type: "object"
      additionalProperties:
        type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "Ответ содержит перечень параметров"
      schema:
        type: "object"
        additionalProperties:
          type: "object"
  security:
  - basicAuth: []
```

This is generated back method with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Приём SMS команды", nickname = "onIncomingSm", notes = "Принимает список параметров в формате json, например {\"sender\":\"nip-sos-pusher\",\"version\":\"v0\",\"method\":\"receivedText\",\"rcvtime\":\"2017-11-13T15:07:40.82632+03:00\",\"profile\":\"poisk_ctl\",\"id\":\"b712bc88-2a96-434a-8420-79d35456b8e0\",\"subscriberId\":\"msisdn+79111115782\",\"priority\":0,\"message\":\"OK 79111113849\"}", response = Object.class, responseContainer = "Map", authorizations = {
    @Authorization(value = "basicAuth")
}, tags={ "sms", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ответ содержит перечень параметров", response = Map.class, responseContainer = "Map") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/sms",
    produces = { "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }, 
    consumes = { "application/json;charset=utf-8" },
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> onIncomingSm(@ApiParam(value = "Список параметров в формате json" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody Object body);
```

Where is a problem? Why response of my method is Map(String, OBJECT) instead of Map(String, STRING) and type of argument is Object instead of Map(String, String)?

Comment: In your config file, you have `additionalProperties: type: "string"` for the input, but for the output you have `additionalProperties: type: "object"`.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel yes this yaml generated by swagger-maven-plugin from source method, but input even converts to Object while should be Map(String, String)